# OpenGL texture on sphere

Tags: android, opengl-es

With this function I can create a sphere in OpenGL ES 1.0 for Android:

```
public Ball(GL10 gl, float radius) 
{
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(40000);
    bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

    sphereVertex = bb.asFloatBuffer();
    points = build();
}

private int build() 
{
    double dTheta = STEP * Math.PI / 180;
    double dPhi = dTheta;

    int points = 0;

    for(double phi = -(Math.PI/2); phi <= Math.PI/2; phi+=dPhi)
    {
        for(double theta = 0.0; theta <= (Math.PI * 2); theta+=dTheta)
        {
            sphereVertex.put((float) (raduis * Math.sin(phi) * Math.cos(theta)));
            sphereVertex.put((float) (raduis * Math.sin(phi) * Math.sin(theta)));
            sphereVertex.put((float) (raduis * Math.cos(phi)));

            points++;
        }
    }

    sphereVertex.position(0);
    return points;
}

public void draw() 
{
    texture.bind();

    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, sphereVertex);

    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, points);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
}
```

My problem now is that I want to use [this texture](http://us.cdn3.123rf.com/168nwm/julydfg/julydfg1104/julydfg110400032/9293053-fussball-ball-textur--abbildung.jpg) for the sphere but then only a black ball is created (of course because the top right corner s black). I use this texture coordinates because I want to use the whole texture:

```
0|0    0|1    1|1    1|0
```

What do I have to do to use the texture correctly?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to setup UV (texture Cords) for each point on the sphere that match up to the texture you provide. Here is a link to some information on UV mapping.

[UV Mapping a Sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UV_mapping)

Answer (score 2):

Just Download and use the code and you can change the image with the image you want

```
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0By5c3cOVKbFpVTFpUlFlV2pGVWM/edit?pli=1
```